# Regex to Validate a String

Tags: regex

I have a string and validate with regex. My requirement to validate the string is

- Total length is 9 characters
- First letter should be Alphabetic [A-Za-z]
- Second letter should be AlphaNumeric (either alphabetic or number)
- remaining 7 characters should be number.

Actually I am using the following expression but it's validating first two characters are Alphabetic and remaining 7 characters are numeric and length also validating.

```
^[A-Z]{2,2}\d{7,7}$
```

How can I write the regex to validate first character is Alphabetic and Second character is either alphabetic or numeric?

Comment: `^[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z0-9]{7}$`?

Answer (score 1):

- First letter should be Alphabetic [A-Za-z] --> `^[A-Za-z]`
- Second letter should be AlphaNumeric (either alphabetic or number) --> `[A-Za-z0-9]`
- remaining 7 characters should be number  -->  `[0-9]{7}$`

Group all them tigether:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9][0-9]{7}$
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/VIburD/1)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it's all working fine now.

The regex is : ^[A-Z]{1,1}[A-Za-z0-9]\d{7,7}$

Comment: (1) The question indicates that the first character can be a lower-case letter.  This regex won’t match a string whose first character is a lower-case letter.  (2) There’s no need to say `{1,1}`.  (3) If this regex works for you, great, but beware that not all programs recognize `\d`.  More portable alternatives include `[0-9]` (to match the ten “Arabic” numerals commonly used in western languages) and `[[:digit:]]` (which may match numeric characters from other alphabets — sorry if that’s an oxymoron).  (4) Instead of `{7,7}`, you can use `{7}`.